# getting PPP socket

Tags: linux, sockets, linux-kernel, ppp, pppd

I am trying to deal with my OS task. By the task, i need to somehow access pppox_sock structure in kernel module and return it to the user space. I tried to create pppox_sock with command

```
pppd passive -detach crtscts lock 10.2.10.2:192.168.31.249 /dev/tty34 38400
```

the result is

```
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/tty34
LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
```

as i have no second computer connect to. Nevertheless, the process is still running due to passive option.
In my kernel module i try to iterate over all available struct net with

```
for_each_net
```

and check sock in it if it has PF_PPPOX family. But all of them not PF_PPPOX.
Do i do right to create socket? How can i create it and access in different way?